# Erro ao salvar Dados SQLite (no such table)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Classe DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String BANCO_DADOS = "MakeRequestApp";
private static int VERSAO = 1;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, BANCO_DADOS, null, VERSAO);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mesa (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, descricao TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE pedido(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, numero_mesa_id INTEGER, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(numero_mesa_id) REFERENCES mesa(_id))");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE itens_pedido (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, produto_id INTEGER, quantidade INTEGER," +
            "FOREIGN KEY(produto_id) REFERENCES produto(_id))");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE pedido(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, numero_mesa_id INTEGER)" +
            "FOREIGN KEY(numero_mesa_id) REFERENCES mesa(_id)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE produto (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, descricao TEXT, valor DOUBLE)");
}
```

Classe do meu Activity:

```
public class MesaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private DatabaseHelper helper;
private EditText descricao;
public static final String MESA_ID = "_id";
private String id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mesa);

    descricao = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtDescricao);
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    id = getIntent().getStringExtra(MESA_ID);

    if (id != null){
        prepararEdicao();
    }
}

private void prepararEdicao(){

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    helper.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void salvarMesa(View view){
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("descricao", descricao.getText().toString());

    long resultado;


    if (id == null){
        resultado = db.insert("mesa", null, values);
    } else {
        resultado = db.update("mesa", values, "_ID= ?", new String[]{id});
    }

    if (resultado != -1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Dados salvos com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Erro ao salvar dados!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Ao tentar salvar dados dá o seguinte erro:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: mesa
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting descricao=8
              android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: mesa (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO mesa(descricao) VALUES (?)
              #################################################################
              Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
              Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                (no such table: mesa (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO mesa(descricao) VALUES (?))
```

Comment: Mude o valor de VERSAO para 2(`private static int VERSAO = 2;`) e volte a testar.

Comment: Acredito que ainda gerará problema se foi um acréscimo. É preciso criar um script de migração para não tentar gerar tabelas que já existem.

Comment: @Wakim Tem razão, o AP não mostra a implementação do método `onUpgrade()`. Parti do pressuposto que é feito o *drop* de todas as tabelas.

Comment: Será que minha tabela não foi criada?

Comment: Você mudou o número de versão como eu sugeri?

Comment: Testei o seu código e o único erro que deu foi **table pedido already exists**. De facto você está a criar a tabela "pedido" duas vezes, veja no `onCreate()` da DatabaseHelper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A única coisa de errado que vejo no seu código(no que se refere à criação do banco) é o facto de estar a criar a tabela "pedido" duas vezes.

Devido a isso, quando testei o seu código recebi o erro:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table pedido already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE pedido(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, numero_mesa_id INTEGER)FOREIGN KEY(numero_mesa_id) REFERENCES mesa(_id)

De resto o seu código funciona como esperado.

Se por acaso a tabela "mesa" tenha sido acrescentada após o banco ter sido criado, terá de incrementar o número de versão e implementar o método `onUpdate()` de forma às alterações serem efectuadas.

Em alternativa, se os dados existentes no banco podem ser descartados desinstale a aplicação e volte a instalar.

Durante o processo de desenvolvimento a implementação do método `onUpdate()` pode apenas fazer o *DROP* das tabela e voltar a criá-las.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String BANCO_DADOS = "MakeRequestApp";
    private static int VERSAO = 1;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, BANCO_DADOS, null, VERSAO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        criaTabelas(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("Drop Table IF EXISTS produto");
        db.execSQL("Drop Table IF EXISTS itens_pedido");
        db.execSQL("Drop Table IF EXISTS pedido");
        db.execSQL("Drop Table IF EXISTS mesa");

        criaTabelas(db);
    }

    private void criaTabelas(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mesa (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, descricao TEXT)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE pedido(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, numero_mesa_id INTEGER, " +
                "FOREIGN KEY(numero_mesa_id) REFERENCES mesa(_id))");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE itens_pedido (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, produto_id INTEGER, quantidade INTEGER," +
                "FOREIGN KEY(produto_id) REFERENCES produto(_id))");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE produto (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, descricao TEXT, valor DOUBLE)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que percebes você tenta criar 2 tabelas com o nome `pedido`, sendo assim veja abaixo o ocorrente erro abaixo:

> SQLiteException: table pedido already exists (code 1): , while
>   compiling: CREATE TABLE pedido(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, numero_mesa_id
>   INTEGER) FOREIGN KEY(numero_mesa_id) REFERENCES mesa(_id)

Fiz a alteração no seu método `onCreate()` removendo a linha que tenta criar a segunda tabela com o nome `pedido` e ficou desta forma abaixo:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE mesa (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, descricao TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE pedido(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, numero_mesa_id INTEGER, " +
            " FOREIGN KEY(numero_mesa_id) REFERENCES mesa(_id))");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE itens_pedido (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, produto_id INTEGER, quantidade INTEGER," +
            " FOREIGN KEY(produto_id) REFERENCES produto(_id))");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE produto (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, descricao TEXT, valor DOUBLE)");
}
```

Fiz até um método para retornar todos os valores inseridos na tabela `mesa` no `DatabaseHelper` e retorna perfeitamente os valores da coluna `descricao`:

```
public List<String> getAll() {
    List<String> todos = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM mesa";

    Log.e("HELPER", selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String item = c.getString((c.getColumnIndex("descricao")));
            // adding to todo list
            todos.add(item);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return todos;
}
```

Comment: Sei que a participação no SO tem associado alguma(muita) competição mas uma coisa que eu não faço nunca é aproveitar um comentário de outro para postar uma resposta. Além que o erro que o AP apresenta nada tem haver com a duplicação da tabela "pedido". Já tinha uma resposta preparada que irei colocar.

Comment: @ramaral mas é serio mesmo, eu não tinha lido. Talvez no tempo em que eu estava resolvendo a questão, você inseriu ele. Mas não quero causar desavenças aqui, considerando que pra mim o unico objetivo mesmo é ajudar, e claro, aprender também.

Comment: @ramaral e sinceramente, não lembro em nenhum caso ter aproveitado de comentário de outra pessoa para publicar uma resposta. Talvez você esteja um pouco precipitado em achar que aconteceu isso, porque na verdade não está deste lado da tela para perceber se de fato ocorreu isso ou não. Eu não tinha uma resposta pronta, comecei analisar a questão no momento em que apareceu a recompensa. Se você já tinha uma resposta, eu nem ninguém poderia adivinhar, mesmo se adivinhassem, talvez seria com outra alternativa de código, etc.

Comment: Acredito que não tenha visto o comentário, não se preocupe com isso. Eu encaro essas situações como competição mesmo(na desportiva). Apenas não pode deixar de comentar a situação. A questão não está em responder, mas no facto de responder o mesmo que estava no meu comentário. Não tinha ainda colocado uma resposta porque aguardava o *feedback* do AP. Queria responder ao perguntado e não apenas sinalizar a questão da tabela "pedido". Foi o que fiz na minha resposta, sugerindo algumas soluções para resolver o problema perguntado.